# Facing issue with Mozilla while performing click action using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

The following is the HTML of web page :

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">                   
<section class="product-cell">
<div class="product-cell-inner ribbon-item ">
<div class="product-thumb">
<a href="/bath/product/P18437-BN" target="_self">
<img class="img-responsive center-block" src="https://media.peerlessfaucet.com/elvis/OnWhite/sm/P18437-BN-B1.png">
 </a>
</div>
<div class="product-info">
<div class="product-heading" style="height: 104px;">
 <button class="product-image-button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#product-modal-3489cb3e-45ff-4e14-9d03-308c78090ed6" data-image="https://media.peerlessfaucet.com/elvis/OnWhite/md/P18437-BN-B1.png" data-details="/bath/product/P18437-BN">View Larger</button>
 <h5><a href="/bath/product/P18437-BN">Tub and Shower Complete</a></h5>
 </div>
 <div class="product-info-inner">
 <div class="product-info-inner-border" style="height: 61px;">
 <dl class="dl-horizontal">
<dt>Model:</dt>
<dd>P18437-BN</dd>
<dt>List price as shown:<sup>1</sup></dt>    
<dd class="price">$198.50</dd>                    
</dl>
 </div>
<a class="more-less">
<span class="less">Less Information <b><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top"></span></b></span>
<span class="more">More Information <b><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span></b></span>
</a>
 <div class="extended-content hidden">   
<h6 class="available-finishes">Available Finishes:</h6>
<ul class="finishes">
 <li><a href="/bath/product/P18437-BN" class="replaced finish-link bn selected">
<span class="facet-thumb facetfinish" style="background: url(/files/live/sites/peerless/files/sprites/sprite-filter-finishes.jpg) no-repeat -296px 0px;
width: 37px;
height: 37px;"></span>
</a></li>  
</ul>                    
 <p class="specs-link"><a href="/bath/product/P18437-BN">View Specs, Dimensions, Installation Instructions, and Parts Diagrams</a></p>
</div>
 </div>
 /div>
<div class="add-to-compare">
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="P18437-BN" name="modelNumber">Add to Compare</label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

I wrote the below code to click on the first element :

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("product-thumb"));
System.out.println("The numbers of elements in page--->"+elements.size());
System.out.println("first element name is---->"+(elements.get(0).getText()));
elements.get(0).click();
```

I want to open first element out of list. Same code working in chrome, but while executing in Mozilla it shows element has clicked but actually it is not cicking. So my script getting fail. Could you please help me on the same?

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to click on the element identified as `<a href="/bath/product/P18437-BN" target="_self">` you need to consider the following :

- As per the *HTML* :

  ```
  <div class="product-thumb">
      <a href="/bath/product/P18437-BN" target="_self">
          <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="https://media.peerlessfaucet.com/elvis/OnWhite/sm/P18437-BN-B1.png">
      </a>
  </div>
  ```
- `By.className("product-thumb")` will identify only this above single parent `<div>` element.
- Hence size will be always **1**
- The node itself have no text hence `getText()` will return **null**.
- To click on the `<a>` tag you can simplify your code block as follows :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='product-thumb']/a")).click();
  ```